# Gtk#: Safe storage of the user's password

Tags: c#, security, gtk#

I use Gtk# and my program must to store user's password. I found, [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class of .NET Framework, but I cann't find this Gtk#'s class. Can you tell me, how to store user's password?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Mono does include `ProtectedData`, I'm not sure how complete it is but it will run the sample off MSDN at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Gtk# on Linux you may want to use the desktop-agnostic secret-service DBUS API that, in theory, should integrate with the user's preferred desktop. See http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-specs/tree/secret-service/.